# In SQL rollback transaction, from where it rollbacks the state?

Tags: sql, rollback

In SQL rollback transaction, from where it rollbacks the state? I mean where the data is stored so that rollback can take it back.

Comment: That is implementation-specific.

Comment: The transaction log. SQL When an update happens in SQL Server, it happens in the transaction log first, then the data is written, so when it rolls back, it removes the t-log entries, and the state of the DB is as it was before the transaction happened. edit* SQL Server specific.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle, it is saving changes in redo log until commit. Every RDMS has own strategy.

Comment: It's actually the UNDO in Oracle, not the redo.

Answer (score 0):

you can use safe and easy code for run 100% (run all line of query) or no run any off them

|query 1| = like insert into or select or ...
|count of lines| = number off query

```html
    DECLARE @rowcount int  set @rowcount = 0 ; 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]
    BEGIN TRY 
     <Query 1> ; set @rowcount = (@rowcount + @@ROWCOUNT); 
     <Query 2> ; set @rowcount = (@rowcount + @@ROWCOUNT); 
    ...
    IF @rowcount =  <count of lines>
      COMMIT TRANSACTION[Tran1]
    ELSE
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION[Tran1]
    END TRY
      BEGIN CATCH
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION[Tran1]
    END CATCH
```

for example this code run 2 insert into line query but or run all of him or no run anything and ROLLBACK

```html
DECLARE @rowcount int  set @rowcount = 0 ; 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]
    BEGIN TRY 
     insert into [database].[dbo].[tbl1] (fld1) values('1') ;
        set @rowcount = (@rowcount + @@ROWCOUNT); 
     insert into [database].[dbo].[tbl2] (fld1) values('2') ;
        set @rowcount = (@rowcount + @@ROWCOUNT); 

    IF @rowcount =  2
      COMMIT TRANSACTION[Tran1]
    ELSE
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION[Tran1]
    END TRY
      BEGIN CATCH
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION[Tran1]
    END CATCH
```